# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen in landscape mode in a portrait project

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape-portrait

in my app i have selected only the portrait mode in the project setting:

[image]

and i use it in this way:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[player setContentURL:videoURL];
[player play];
```

but when i display a video using `MPMoviePlayerController` in full screen and i try to rotate it, doens't rotate, and stay in `portrait`, there is a simple way without enable the `landscape` mode in the project setting, to active the `landscape` in fullscreen?

Comment: i think you should try using customMoviePlayer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Enable landscape mode in the project settings and override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` for your view controllers.
2. In your app delegate, add the `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method and, when playing a movie, make sure that this returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`.

Comment: can you make an example for the option 2? when playing the movie i have to change the method in app delegate? or in the view controller?

Comment: App delegate. In your app delegate you can listen for `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` to enable rotating to landscape and listen for `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification` to disable it.

Comment: @GuyKogus I'm trying to implement this solution in swift, when i try to add `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:", name: MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification, object: nil)` to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it throws unresolved identifier MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Did you call `import MediaPlayer` at the top of the file?