# Rotated MPMoviePlayerController is missing controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to rotate my MPMoviePlayerController and am doing so as follows:

```
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:selectedImageURL];
    [self.player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    self.player.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2*3);
    self.player.view.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
    [self.player play];
```

With the rotated video, though, I don't see the controls.

**How do I ensure that the controls are in view?**

Also, as a related question, is there a way to specify the placement of the controls?  I'd like the controls to appear on the bottom of the screen for portrait videos and on the right of the screen for landscape videos.

**Test Video**

You can try out the code with this video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1000620/lego_test.mp4

Comment: Why do you need to rotate the view? Clearly this messes up the view, so there's your problem. You should let your _app's entire interface_ rotate in the normal way (i.e. through your root view controller). As for the controls, no, you can set the style but you don't get to set the placement; the workaround, not pleasant, would be to write your own controls.

Comment: The issue is that videos appear in the wrong orientation with initWithContentURL.  I need to selectively rotate video that was shot in portrait mode on the iPhone device (see test link above).  This issue has nothing to do with rotating the device itself into different viewing modes.

Comment: But how did that video get into this state in the first place? A video shot in portrait orientation won't behave like that. It looks like a rotation has been deliberately applied to that video. So first you're wrongly applying a 90-degree rotation to the video and then you're complaining that the video has been rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Well, let me know if you have a better suggestion for playing that video correctly besides rotating the entire view. You haven't suggested any alternative.

Comment: Yes I have: my alternative is Don't Do That. And you haven't explained why you've got a messed-up video on your hands. - But if you insist: It depends how the video was acquired. If it's on disk (in your app, let's say) I'd use AVFoundation to save a new copy correctly rotated; now the display will be correct. If you're streaming it over the network, though, you've no alternative to what you're doing and you'll probably just have to make your own controls if you want controls. I'm pretty sure you can find third-party control widgets that imitate the built-in controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think video playing and processing should be handled separately. In fact, I think MPMoviePlayerController is only capable of playing video. (Am I wrong?)

Video playing: 
Customized control should includes some steps as follow:
1) set controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
2) add a overlay view to containerView, place your controls on this view;
3) make MPMoviePlayerController handling controls events.
Example "MoviePlayer" shows how to add overlay view to MPMoviePlayerController.

if you just want to rotate video playing in fullscreen, the following link will be help

[MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen in landscape mode in a portrait project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424693/mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-in-landscape-mode-in-a-portrait-project)

Video processing is another thing. Maybe you need reading Example "AVSimpleEditoriOS".

By using AVFoundation framework, you can reading frames from video, processing (rotate, zoom), writing to displaying buffer in real time.